# Using CSS-Selectors in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do you give a `<p>` tag element inside a third `<div>` tag element in an HTML source code a background color in using CSS Selectors?

Comment: yeah, where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector for this.

```css
.container div:nth-child(3) p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>I'm</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Bob</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well solution is great buh the changes affected just the first paragraph tag element instead of both of them....I'm sorry I should have added that lil info earlier when asking my question

Comment: The division element has no class and I'm new here so i don't even know how to approve your answer on this platform unless I add an approval comment under it.

Comment: Well i just discovered I made an error typing my HTML source code at that particular division element i forgot to type the second paragraph tag element buh I have done that now... About your solution code you typed... Just remove the "container" class cause the division tag elment in my source code has no class

Comment: Since you did not provide your code in the question, I just had to guess with the HTML structure. Just replace `.container` with whatever div is containing your multiple divs. Otherwise, if you just say, `div:nth-child(3)`, it will select the third child of every div on your page.

Comment: Let me ask a quick question whiles I'm still on the subject... How do I make changes to the second paragraph tag (under the same 3rd division tag elment ) element only?

Comment: It's probably best if you create a new question instead of asking one in the comments. That way, if someone else has the same problem, they can quickly find a question relating to it. But this time please post some relevant code so that the developers can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Is there any way to actually chat with someone who can help me out and not have to wait an hour and half later...?

Comment: Hunter: _"remove the > selector, which only selects the first p tag"_ *No*, the `>` child selector would select every `<p>` that is a child of the selected `<div>` — @Edward : _"changes affected just the first paragraph tag element instead of both of them"_ • I don't see how this could be; adding a second `<p>` to each of the divs in Hunter's answer worked both with or without the `>` ... the only difference is -- Is the **p** an immediate child of the **div** `<div><p>...</p>`, or is it a deeper descendant? `<div><section><p>...</p>...` •• **chat:** there is a link at the bottom of this page.

Comment: @StephenP You're definitely right. I wasn't thinking when I said that.